# Fabric missing DSYMs even though log says it uploaded them

Tags: ios, jenkins, crashlytics, google-fabric

For my iOS app I use Jenkins to distribute my test builds. I use Fabric for crash reporting. I run the post build scripts on Jenkins to upload ipa, release notes and DSYMs to Fabric. This is the script I run to upload DSYMs:

```
${WORKSPACE}/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -a {api-key} -p ios ${WORKSPACE}/artifacts/TestDebug-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.app.dSYM
```

[source for the script](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html)

In the build logs on Jenkins I see:

> upload-symbols[91261:22647730] Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID {uuid1} in dSYM: /Users/jenkins/build/workspace/{my_app}/artifacts/TestDebug-iphoneos/Myapp.app.dSYM
>
> upload-symbols[91261:22647730] Successfully submitted symbols for architecture armv7 with UUID {uuid2} in dSYM: /Users/jenkins/build/workspace/{my_app}/artifacts/TestDebug-iphoneos/Myapp.app.dSYM

However, I still see missing DSYMs on Fabric. I looked at the UUIDs that Fabric is missing, and they do not match to anything on my build machine. Neither they match the uuid1 or uuid2 from my build log above.

Did anyone ran into the the same issue?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. There could be a number of things going on, but let's start with a couple of foundational questions on dSYMs. Are you using Bitcode and distributing the app to TestFlight in addition to Fabric?

Comment: HI Mike, we are not distributing the app via TestFlight

Comment: Gotcha, the next thing to check would be if you have any static frameworks linked in, if so check the following settings?

"Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" -> NO
"Strip Linked Product" -> NO
"Use Separate Strip" -> NO

Comment: In my case "Strip Linked Product" -> YES, see the image in the edit

Comment: Ok, try setting it to No and see if that improves things on your next build.

Comment: tried that, and it doesn't seem to work...still see the missing dSYMs message :( @MikeBonnell

Comment: If you run dwarfdump -u <PathToDsym> does the dSYM match the one reported as missing?

Comment: so I found the missing DSYMs inside MyProject.xarchive package inside the artifacts folder on my server build machine. The files that fabric is uploading with the script I provided above come from the files that look like this (UUID.bcsymbolmap)...no idea what that is...

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite the script to go to .xarchive package, grab dSYMs folder, zip it and upload it, instead of ${PROJECT_NAME}.app.dSYM from my example above? @MikeBonnel

Comment: OMG!!! I think I figured it out...I used this script instead of the one I used before: find ${WORKSPACE}/artifacts/MyApp.xcarchive/dSYMs -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} ${WORKSPACE}/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -a <api-key> -p ios \{\}

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution by using this script:

find ${WORKSPACE}/artifacts/MyApp.xcarchive/dSYMs -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I {} ${WORKSPACE}/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -a  -p ios {}

Comment: from the Crashlytics docs, 1 file is enough. Search log for `export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME=`