# Fabric/Crashlytics stopped showing adequate stacktrace for iOS app

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

My app is integrated with Fabric, and I was able to see crash stack traces for a long time. All of a sudden recently I noticed that the crash reports stopped making sense. All I see for my app stack trace is this:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  myApp                 0x102a005b0 _hidden#5298_ (__hidden#5526_:499)
1  myApp                 0x102a018e0 _hidden#5310_ (__hidden#5526_:346)
2  myApp                 0x102a0f1e4 _hidden#5361_ (__hidden#5526_)
3  myApp                 0x102bc00e0 _hidden#1801_ (__hidden#19024_)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x180e48b24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x180e48ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x180e89d60 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 964
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1814ff070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1814fcbc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18141cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
10 GraphicsServices               0x1833ff020 GSEventRunModal + 100
11 UIKit                          0x18b3fd78c UIApplicationMain + 236
12 myApp                 0x10299bc14 main (__hidden#1255_:18)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x180eadfc0 start + 4
```

Fabric is not reporting any dSYMs missing or anything.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: "Fabric is not reporting any dSYMs missing or anything" Well, yes it is, insofar as the term `hidden` appears for your app. See https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html for solutions.

Comment: Hi @matt I did check out that document. Maybe I did miss something though...so I had another issue in the past ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928498/fabric-missing-dsyms-even-though-log-says-it-uploaded-them ) and fixed it with the help on a guy from Fabric, see the thread from link above. So if you know something about my problem, can you please elaborate more. Thank you

Comment: I have the exact same problem @EugeneGordin! Everything worked fine until now. I am guessing Fabric made a change in their dSYM processing since I haven't changed my Xcode setup.